# C++: Update a QList efficiently

Tags: c++, qt, iterator

I have a `QList<float>`.
I want to loop over it to copy its values in another `QList` and to change the negative values to 0 on the go.

I successfully iterated on the input list. But I don't know how to update the size of the output one.
Here is what I tried:

```
void resetNegValuesToZero(
        QList<float> &out, const QList<float> &in)
{
    // Create iterators for Qlists
    QList<float>::const_iterator i;
    QList<float>::iterator o = out.begin();

    // Loop over inputs and assign output list
    for (i = in.begin(); i != in.end(); ++i, ++o)
        if (*i<0) *o = 0;
        else *o = *i;

}
```

I wanted to avoid using the `append` method. But, I realize that maybe its impossible since I could corrupt the memory...
But I'd like to be sure!

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`QList` implements copy-on-write so you may simplify your code:

```
void resetNegValuesToZero(const QList<float> &in) {
    QList<float> out = in;
    for (QList<float>::iterator o = out.begin(); o != out.end(); ++o) {
        if (*o < 0) {
            *o = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

If you can't create a new `QList` for out and it must be a parameter from outside then you should at least reserve enough space for all elements you will need (reallocation is something pretty slow):

```
void resetNegValuesToZero(QList<float> &out, const QList<float> &in) {
    QList<float>::const_iterator it = in.begin();

    out.reserve(in.count()); // Assuming out is empty
    for (int i=0; it != in.end(); ++it, ++i)
        out.insert(i, *it < 0 ? 0 : *it);
}
```

Comment: So you mean it is faster to copy the list and then update it. That's exactly what I wanted to avoid!! Could you tell me why this is faster than emptying an existing list and then assigning all values one by one? Thanks!

Comment: BTW I can change the interface of the function. I have some freedom in this part of the dev. I'll give it a try!

Comment: If existing list is big enough then yes, it's faster to empty and fill. If size is not enough then copy-on-write is slightly faster and it may be cache friendly (if values have a pattern or they are ordered). You're absolutely right: measure it with your real data. As fallback you always have resize()  on an EMPTY list.

Comment: I had to read your answer several times and I finally realized I missed something big. I missed the COW thing that I have never heard about before! At first I though the `QLists` where replicated. I just understood it is not the case. I read basic some basic stuff about COW (wikipedia), and your answer just blow my mind. I still don't get the cache part, by its probably too much for me at the moment ;). Thanks!

Comment: BTW, I am giving you the answer. I could be interesting for other people to discover the copy on write mechanism!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, `QList` doesn't have a `resize()` method.

I'd personally `clear()` the target list, `reserve()`, then use `append()` or `push_back()` to populate it. That will still avoid reallocating the internal storage.

Naturally, you could always `out = in` and then iterate `out` and alter the values needed. This will copy the underlying storage of `out`, I assume the operation will be implemented efficiently enough.

Maybe you should consider `QVector` instead - it is slightly more efficient, as it doesn't preallocate space in the beginning, and it does have a full featured API, including reserving and resizing.

Comment: That is what I did so far. Do you know if `append()` avoids scanning the whole list before reaching the target. In other words, does `Qlist` keep a pointer to the last item?

Comment: @Plouff - The list has a size property, and a capacity property, so it will simply check if there is enough capacity and if so put the element after the last one. BTW clearing and copying with append() will be slightly more efficient than assigning the target to the source and then iterating to only alter the needed elements, because it will avoid an extra iteration and the cost of sharing and then detaching the shared resource.

Comment: That is what I was thinking to. I wanted to avoid extra iterations. Few years ago, I would have just use a basic for without iterator `for(int i=0; i < size; i++){ // in[i] }`. But now I try to understand how data structure works. So thanks a lot for your explanations. You might want to consider what Adriano Repetti said in the comments. I mean that copying the data as a whole and then update it could be more efficient on big data sets.